# Identify numbers in one String

Tags: java, methods

I have made this method to get birthday, but I wonder if I can identify the numbers for the months and days in one String

for example

930421 is correct
931360 is not correct

```
public void setFirst(String firstn, int y, int m,int d) {
    first = firstn;
    if (first.length() == 6){
        System.out.println("Your birthday is :" +first);

    }else {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: String.substring and Integer.parseInt seem useful here

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with a pattern such as `yyMMdd`. Make sure to use `setLenient(false)` to make the parser "strict" so it will actually raise an Exception on invalid dates.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
format.setLenient(false);
```

Example:

```
System.out.println(format.parse("930421"));
System.out.println(format.parse("931360"));
```

Output:

```
Wed Apr 21 00:00:00 CEST 1993
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "931360"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at Test.main(Test.java:12)
```

You can use it like this:

```
try {
    Date date = format.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println("Your birthday is " + date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("That's not a date");
}
```

Comment: Addendum: Note that this method also checks for the allowed number of days in a month (28 to 31) and also handles leap years correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer.
It's working as per your expectation :)

```
static boolean dob = true;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    setFirst("931360", 0, 0, 0);
    setFirst("930421", 0, 0, 0);
}

public static void setFirst(String firstn, int y, int m,int d) {
    String first = firstn;
    if (first.length() == 6){
        y=Integer.parseInt(first.substring(0, 2));
        if(y<0 || y>99)
        {dob=false;}

        m=Integer.parseInt(first.substring(2, 4));
        if(m<1 || m>12)
        {dob=false;}

        d=Integer.parseInt(first.substring(4, 6));
        if(d<0 || d>31)
        {dob=false;}

        if(dob)
        {System.out.println("Your birthday is :" +first);}

    }if(!dob) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date format is yy-mm-dd, you could just: (simple-minded but easy to implement solution)

1) use `String.substring` to get the string segments you need (e.g. first 2 digits for yy),

2) parse an integer out of them with `Integer.parseInt`

3) and check them against a range (e.g. for yy it could be between 20 and 99).

Please note that yy is a representation that is quite prone to error (e.g. 1910 and 2010 are represented in the same way) so you should really consider using yyyy instead.